# My jar file is only 70MB and uncompressed file is 170MB, layer zip file is 3MB and unzipped file is 7MB, still get error

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I am using the serverless framework for the deployment.
My lambda code jar file size is 70MB and unzipped size is 170mb on local.
But when I try to add a layer which zip file is 3MB and unzipped file is 7MB, it get an error: **Code uncompressed size is greater than max allowed size of 272629760.**
Are there any other data when I deploy a lambda?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible - given the information you provided - to see where the error is coming from, since the numbers don't really add up. However, if you're running into size limitations of you zipped deployment package, you could have a look into deploying your lambda as a container (via ECR) instead of as a zip since the size quota is a lot higher in comparison to a zipped deployment package.

Source: [Lambda quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html)

Comment: Thank you for you reply @stijndepestel
> if you're running into size limitations of you zipped deployment package
No, actually my package size is 66MB.
> since the numbers don't really add up
Do you mean the actuall package size is not 170MB + 7MB ? So what's the other data?

Comment: I'm saying that according to the numbers you've provided, you shouldn't be running into these limitations, but the error that you got seems to show that you did run into it. So if you can't seem to find out where the size is coming from, using an image might be a good way to fix it and/or to find out what other things are added to your package.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Since we find our code run well with new AWS Corretto 8 runtime, so we don't need to add a layer for our lambda. Again, still thank you for your reply.
For the lambda size, we found that when we will get  354 MB (file size) from "du -sh" command, but 211.3 MB from file system. Maybe this is the problem.