# Why do I get the error "Code uncompressed size is greater than max allowed size of 272629760" only for some deployment targets?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-codepipeline, aws-lambda-layers

As part of an AWS CodePipeline in an AWS CodeBuild action I deploy resources created with the Serverless Framework to a "UAT" (user acceptance testing) stage.
The pipeline runs in its own tooling AWS account, first deploying cross-account into a separate "UAT" account, then deploying cross-account into a separate "Production" account.

The first deployment to "UAT" completes successfully, whereas the succeeding deployment to "Production" fails with the error ...

```
Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
 
  An error occurred: <some name>LambdaFunction - Resource handler returned message: "Code uncompressed size is greater than max allowed size of 272629760. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: <some request id>, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: <some request token>, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest).
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              14.17.2
     Framework Version:         2.68.0 (local)
     Plugin Version:            5.5.1
     SDK Version:               4.3.0
     Components Version:        3.18.1
```

This started to happen, once I introduced the usage of a private Lambda Layer. The total size of all files seems way less than the maximum allowed size.

This question isn't so much about the actual error (there already exists a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69706481/my-jar-file-is-only-70mb-and-uncompressed-file-is-170mb-layer-zip-file-is-3mb-a)).
I rather wonder why the behavior is inconsistent, varying with the deployment targets. Because the [limits for the Lambda Function package size](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) (including the usage of Lambda Layers) should be the same for all environments.

Comment: Exact same boat here. We added a layer and now we get that max size error too. Did you find a solution? Or are you still dealing with it?

Comment: Ran into a similar issue. Tried to incorporate a (tiny) layer into an existing lambda that had been deployed via S3 due to its size. During `terraform apply`, I got the error `Code uncompressed size is greater than max allowed size of 272629760` only when the layer was in play. Had to deploy a dummy version of the lambda with no dependencies, add the layer, then redeploy. Annoyingly misleading error message, as it made it seem like the size of the **layer** was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a weird issue which I also faced when moving to Lambda layers.

To fix this, as a workaround,

- Comment the lambda layers configuration in your serverless.yml file and deploy it
- Uncomment the lambda layers configuration in your serverless.yml file and deploy it

This steps may look weird but it worked for me